# Websites (static or dynamic) conversion to android app

Tags: android, webview

Let us take a website like Facebook. We access it using a desktop web browser or a mobile web browser. Now, I can also install a Facebook app from the google playstore.

I understand a website can be converted to an android app using WebView layout in android studio.

1. Is that the only way these websites are converted to android apps?
2. Is there a different way that an android app can be developed for a website like facebook other than using WebView? (For eg. Facebook developed as a webapp for desktop/mobile browsers) and developed from scratch using Android Studio without using WebView but still can log in and make updates which reflects on the app as well as mobile/destop browser)
3. Why would there be a different method, if any? Any limitations for webview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) Not necessarily.

2.) For a "dynamic" site, you could develop API's that retrieve the data to be shown on the web pages. These API's could then also be used to build an Android app.

3.) First of all, by using a `WebView`, you would want to carefully design the UI of the website to be responsive and look good for mobile devices. (How it would appear in the `WebView`). On the other hand, if you were to build your app from the ground up, you would be able to basically have a custom implementation of the website in app form. If you were to build server API's and query them over HTTP from the android client, you would probably be able to give it more of an "app" feel, rather than just a website.

Here's an example of both scenarios.

If you wanted to build an app for Facebook, you would do one of the following.

a.) Develop a mobile-friendly version of the website and display it in a `WebView` in the Android app. Done!

b.) Develop server API's to retrieve information that you would find on the Facebook website. (Posts on users walls, photos, etc) Then implement these API's to display data in the Android client using components like `ListView`'s and `ImageView`'s

Comment: Thanks so much! It was clear. The other question I have is that in the two scenarios you mentioned

Comment: Thanks so much! It was clear. The other 2 question I have is that in the two scenarios you mentioned. Firstly, can an android app for the web developed using WebView can be uploaded onto Google playstore? I am guessing that should not be a problem for the custom android app for website using server Api's. Secondly, what kind of apps are usually developed in companies in general....1. An exclusive android app (not a website) (or) 2. a webapp converted to android app using webview (or) 3. a webapp with custom android implementation. Please clarify

Comment: For your first question, it depends. According to google you may not "Provide a webview of a website not owned or administered by you (unless you have permission from the website owner/administrator to do so)" (See more here: https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy/) For your second question, it really depends on the specific need of the company, I don't know that there is a general guideline. I would say that simple / static websites could just use a WebView, but anything more complex than that you will have to weigh the pros and cons of each.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! Feel free to mark this answer as accepted if I sufficiently answered your question. :)

Comment: One more quick question. I plan to become an Android developer. I know a bit how websites are developed but my knowledge is not indepth. Should I be well versed in any webframeworks to convert a website to an android app custom implemented? or is it enough I focus on the Android API guides for the server, fethching data etc..Do you know any resource which would help me learn that.

Comment: To be honest that's a pretty broad question. It all depends on what your website is built on. The Android side is easy enough, there are tons of libraries that make it easy to implement HTTP functionality (example: http://loopj.com/android-async-http/)

Answer (score 1):

```
    webView.setInitialScale(1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.educationboardresults.gov.bd/");
```

Comment: Please make this a full answer, not just a code answer with no explanation.